# How can I resize my partition inside extended partition giving its space from outside of extended partition?

Tags: gparted, partitioning

I am having this set up at the moment :

[image]

and I would like to give the unallocated space between `/dev/sda3/` and `/dev/sda4` to /dev/sda5`. How can I do that now ?

Comment: Do be sure to make a backup first since moving sda5 will take a very long time, and a crash or power failure will trash the partition.  Also the red "!" indicates that there is already something wrong with that partition, so you should take a look at the details to see what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some steps you must follow:

1. You must fix your NTFS partition that is dirty. Boot up Windows, open the command line and type `chkdsk /f X:`, changing X for each of the letter of your volumes. **Reboot twice**.
2. Now with a Live CD without any mounted partition, redimension the `sda4` extended partition to fill the unallocated space. Now that space will be inside the extended partition.
3. Now redimension/move the partitions as you like to fill the now "free space".

That's all

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this on a live CD, unmount all your partitions, including swap, and do it in steps. Right now sda5 and sda6 are mounted, so you can not work with them.

From a live CD, first unmount all your partitions (you  can do this in the gparted menu).

Then, in steps, -> Increase the size of sda4 -> apply changes -> increase the size of sda5 -> apply changes.